# LeapJS zoom gesture within touchzone

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I'm currently trying to implement a pinch-to-zoom gesture in LeapJS. It should be handled if the gesture is performed with two fingers within the touch zone.

But now I'm stuck with that interaction zone stuff, as `pointable.touchZone` doesn't seem to work in my code. It looks something like this:

```
var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures : true});
controller.on('frame', function(frame) {

    if (frame.valid) {
        for (var p = 0; p < frame.pointables.length; p++) {
            var pointable = frame.pointables[p];

            if (pointable.touchZone == 'touching') {
                //if fingers are expanded
                    // detect zoom gesture
                //else
                    // detect pinch gesture
            }
        }

        if (frame.gestures.length > 0) {
            // detect swipe gesture ...
        }
    }

    lastFrame = frame;
});
controller.connect();
```

What is the best way to implement this gesture? Could somebody provide me with an example? I suppose this is pretty simple but unfortunately I'm not experienced with Javascript and Leap Motion...

Thx!

**edit:**
Ok, however, it helped to use the debugger that is integrated in Firefox instead of Firebug... ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working? Is ``(pointable.touchZone == 'touching')'' just never true? Try running the the diagnostic visualizer at the same time as your app and turn on "drawing mode" (``d`` key). This mode draws lines when the fingers are in the "touching" zone so you can compare with what is happening in your app. Also, have a look at the hand.scaleFactor property. It provides you with a value proportional to the expansion/contraction of your fingers and is intended to support pinch/zoom operations. The tricky part is starting and stopping the operation at the appropriate times.

Comment: Hey did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @deemeetree yes! Charles tip to use the hand scalefactor helped me out.

Comment: @user3151809 would you share some code here, please? :)